# Show that the function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ cannot be analytically continued beyond the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$. Show that $f$ cannot be analytically continued beyond the unit disk.

My thought so far: consider a root of unity, say $r=e^{2\pi ik}$, where $k$ is a rational number. Now consider the path $t\rightarrow tr, t\in [0,1]$ I want to show that the sum $\lim_{t\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(tr) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t^{n!}e^{2\pi irn!}$ blows up. Can I use the Abel's theorem here? How do I show that the sum diverges?

Comment: You're on the right track. Just split the sum into the parts where $n < k$ and $n \geq k$ and stare for a while at the terms in the latter one. You'll get there.

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, $e^{2\pi i r n!} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_n:=n!$.

It should be clear that the power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{\lambda_n}$ has convergence radius $1$.

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\lambda_n}=0,$$

Fabry's gap theorem says, that then the circle $|z|=1$ is the natural boundary of $f$

Comment: I wonder what inspired Fabry's gap theorem. The OP's example?